# Compiling complication, extending a class

Tags: java

I have my two classes in a package called beginsthings. FirstClass compiles fine (of course, it doesn't extend anything), but SecondClass extends the first and the compiler is saying it cannot find FirstClass in it. I am trying to compile by going to the directory and typing javac beginsthings/SecondClass.java, am I doing something wrong?

**error:**

```
beginsthings/SecondClass.java:6: cannot find symbol
symbol: class FirstClass
public class SecondClass extends FirstClass {
```

^it wont find the FirstClass being extended. I know the code inside works bc its a sample from a library
and package beginsthings is a folder in a src folder.

**beginsthings/FirstClass.java:**

```
package beginsthings;

//bunch of gui imports
public class FirstClass {

//some code for drawing a circle

}
```

**beginsthings/SecondClass.java:**

```
package beginsthings;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class SecondClass extends FirstClass {

   //code for the drop goes here, but extending FirstClass already doesn't work.
    }
```

Comment: voted down without an answer? someone else had asked this same question and the method i tried was based on the answer in that forum. halp!

Comment: @FredV: You haven't provided enough detail.  Please tell us the exact error, the paths to all of the files, and the package name.

Comment: What is the command you are using to compile and where are you running it from (e.g. are you running javac within the "beginsthings" directory? Do you have a "beginsthings" directory?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either compile both java files at once or else provide the .class file for FirstClass in the classpath when SecondClass compiles.  Try

```
javac beginsthings/*.java
```